# Unable to use pidgin with proxy

Tags: proxy, pidgin, yahoo

I am unable to use Pidgin through my institute network which has proxy(for my *yahoo* account). The solution suggested in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69818/is-there-a-chat-application-that-supports-a-proxy) does not work with me. I did a lot of googling ,yet I couldn't find a good solution. Is it possible to use Pidgin with proxy ?
If it is possible please give me step-by-step instructions to configure it
or please anyone suggest me a very good alternative chat-client in Ubuntu which works with proxy ?